# How can i change welcome page image in my installer?

Tags: nsis

I want to change nsis welcome page default image in welcome screen so i am trying to use following code .But these are showing blank.

CODE:

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\NXP.bmp"
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\NXP.bmp"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How did you create NXP.bmp?

NSIS doesn't accept all BMP variants. I sometimes need to open and save bmp files with Paint in order to be sure it will be a valid BMP file.

Comment: Nice. :-)
I use Gimp too. I've been unable to create valid BMPs for NSIS using Gimp...

Comment: Well, we all know Windows/NSIS is a little silly - the bitmaps are "valid"! When exporting from Gimp, it worked with the following options: Compatibility Options -> Do not write color space information (ticked). Advanced options: 24 bits R8 G8 B8 (ticked). Gimp is probably sensible and saves 32 bit by default, too much for Windows ;) Additionally, the size of the image I used was 150x57px.